# How to set state in parent without triggering re-render of children in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React web app that is effectively a ton of Questions.  These questions need to be validated/laid-out based on their *own* state values (ie: must be a number in a number field), as well as on the values of each other.   A few examples of the more complex 'validation':

- Questions A, B, and C might be required to have non-empty values before allowing a 'save' button.
- Question B's allowable range of values might be dependent on the value of question A.
- Question C  might only show if question A is set to 'true'.

You can imagine many other interactions.  The app has hundreds of questions - as such, I have their configuration in a JSON object like this:

```
{ id: 'version', required: true, label: 'Software Version', xs: 3 },
{
    id: 'licenseType', label: 'License Type', xs: 2,
    select: {
        [DICTIONARY.FREEWARE]: DICTIONARY.FREEWARE,
        [DICTIONARY.CENTER_LICENSE]: DICTIONARY.CENTER_LICENSE,
        [DICTIONARY.ENTERPRISE_LICENSE]: DICTIONARY.ENTERPRISE_LICENSE
    }
},
... etc.
```

I would then turn this object into actual questions using a map in the `FormPage` component, the parent of all the questions. Given the need to store these interaction in the closest common parent, I store all of the `Question` values in a `formData` state variable object and the `FormPage` looks like so:

```
function FormPage(props) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(BLANK_REQUEST.asSubmitted);

    const handleValueChange = (evt, id) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: evt.target.value})
    }

    return <div>
        {QUESTIONS_CONFIG.map(qConfig => <Question  qConfig={qConfig} value={formData[qConfig.id]} handleValueChange={handleValueChange}/>)}
        // other stuff too
    </div>
}
```

The `Question` component is basically just a glorified [material UI textField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) that has it's value set to `props.value` and it's `onChange` set to `props.handleValueChange`.  The rest of the `qConfig` object and `Question` component is about layout and irrelevant to the question.

The problem with this approach was that every keypress results in the `formData` object changing... which results in a re-render of the `FormPage` component... which then results in a complete re-render/rebuild of all my hundreds of `Question` components.  It technically works, but results performance so slow you could watch your characters show up as you type.

---

To attempt solve this, I modified `Question` to hold it's own value in it's own state and we no longer pass `formData` to it...  the `Question` component looking something like this:

```
function Question(props) {
    const { qConfig, valueChangedListener, defaultValue } = props;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (qConfig.value && typeof defaultValue !== 'undefined') {
            setValue(qConfig.value);
        }
    }, [qConfig.value])


    const handleValueChange = (evt, id) => {
        setValue(evt.target.value);
        valueChangedListener(evt.target.value, id)
    }

    return <div style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>
        <TextField
            // various other params unrelated...
            value={value ? value : ''}
            onChange={(evt) => handleValueChange(evt, qConfig.id)}
        >
        // code to handle 'select' questions.
        </TextField>
    </div>
}
```

Notably, now, when it's value changes, it stores it's own value only lets `FormPage` know it's value was updated so that `FormPage` can do some multi-question validation.

To finish this off, on the `FormPage` I added a callback function:

```
const processValueChange = (value, id) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value })
};
```

and then kept my useEffect that does cross-question validation based on the formData:

```
useEffect(() => { // validation is actually bigger than this, but this is a good example
        let missingArr = requiredFields.filter(requiredID => !formData[requiredID]);
        setDisabledReason(missingArr.length ? "Required fields (" + missingArr.join(", ") + ") must be filled out" : '');
}, [formData, requiredFields]);
```

the return from `FormPage` had a minor change to this:

```
return <div>
    {questionConfiguration.map(qConfig => 
        <Question
            qConfig={qConfig}
            valueChangedListener={processValueChange}
        />
    </ div>
    )
}
```

---

Now, my problem is -- ALL of the questions *still* re-render on every keypress...

I thought that perhaps the function I was passing to the `Question` component was being re-generated so I tried wrapping `processValueChange` in a useCallback:

```
const processValueChange = React.useCallback((value, id) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value })
    }
},[]);
```

but that didn't help.

My guess is that even though `formData` (a state object on the `FormPage`) is not used in the return... its modification is still triggering a full re-render every time.

But I need to store the value of the children so I can do some stuff with those values.

... but if I store the value of the children in the parent state, it re-renders everything and is unacceptbaly slow.

I do not know how to solve this?  Help?

How would a functional component store all the values of its children (for validation, layout, etc)... without triggering a re-render on every modification of said data?  (I'd only want a re-render if the validation/layout function found something that needed changing)

EDIT:
Minimal sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-ritchie-b0yki

I have a console.log in the Question component so we can see when they render.

Comment: It's going to be a combination of `useMemo` and `useCallback`, most likely. Hard to say exactly how without a [mre]

Comment: I'll look to build a code-sandbox quick...